# Priority for Try-catch with Throws in Java

Tags: java, try-catch, throws

I heard that `try+catch` or `throws` can be used to throw an exception. But if they both are used in a context which one will be executed.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
    try
    {
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String s=br.readLine();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Catching an exception and declaring it in a throws clause are not "used to throw an exception". They are the two ways you can handle a checked exception that might be thrown inside your method (or by a method called by your method). You can either handle it inside the method by catching it, or declare it in a throws clause, to let the users of your method know they should handle it.

If you are catching all the exceptions in your method (as `catch(Exception e)` does), there's no meaning to having a throws clause, since your method will never throw an `IOException`.

Comment: What about if I catch exception e and wrap it under a custom exception and throw from catch clause.

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj In that case, if the custom exception is a checked exception, it (or one of its super classes) must be declared in a throws clause.

Answer (score 1):

If your program en counted a exception inside a `try{}` it will jump to `catch(Exception e){}` block.

If you occurred an exception  **inside your method but outside `try{}` and `catch(Exception e){}`** it will throws it out of the method.

Whether the method will goes to `catch(Exception e){}` block or `throws` ; that will depend on the place where the exception is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

In your case the catch block will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

A`throws`clause is used to declare any checked exception classes (§11.1.1) that
the statements in a method or constructor body can throw (§11.2.2).
Whereas `catch` block is used for catching all types of Exceptions.
An exception thrown from a `try` block will be caught in `catch` block.
So here `catch` block will be executed

Answer (score 0):

An exception can be *thrown* and *handled* (caught). The first is done either explicitly by the `throw` keyword or implicitly (for example, if you divide an integer by 0). The second is done by a `try...catch` block. The `throws` clause mentioned by you neither throws nor handles an exception (see below).

If an exception is thrown, normal execution stops immediately and the appropriate catch block is executed. After that, execution proceeds after the `try...catch` block.

So what does the `throws` clause do? In some cases, you don't want to handle an exception yourself. You want the exeception to propagate to the code that calls your method so that it can handle the exception and take appropriate action. The `throws` clause says nothing more than: "Beware! This method may (not must) throw an exception of the given type, so you'd better add error handling for it!". (In some cases, in particular if your code or code called by your code throws a so-called *checked* exception but does catch it, it is required to add a `throws` clause to the method declaration; in other cases it is optional.)

In your case, the code

```
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String s=br.readLine();
```

can throw an `IOException`. Since the code occurs within in `try` block which contains a `catch` block `IOException`s, it is not necessary to add the `throws` clause. It is allowed, though, although in your case it is spurious because your code cannot throw an unhandled `IOException`.